# Why axios remove "Bearer" string from authorization header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I've had a problem with axios and GET request with using Bearer token. Here is my code:

```
      const response = await axios.post("/auth/login", {
        ...form
      });

      const token = response["token"];
      if (token) {
        localStorage.setItem("session", token);

        console.log(token); //a234o2i3nr203fn20jef0293...
        const tokenHeader = {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }

        const projects = await axios.get('/projects', { headers: { "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}});
        console.log(projects); //UNAUTHORIZED

      }
```

After login to account I want to immediately fetch data about projects, so I use axios and try to use `axios.get` with authorization header. But, for unknown for me reason, to my server part request has been delivered but without `Bearer` string before my `token`, my server had this on this request:

```
headers: {
    authorization: "a234o2i3nr203fn20jef0293..." //axios remove `Bearer` string?
}
```

becuase of this, I cannot return any value because my server return me unauthorized cause this:

```
    const token = authHeaders && authHeaders.split(" ")[1];
```

return me null instead of token.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this axios request?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: its confusing you have `token` header and passing headers differently

Comment: have you checked the network tab in browser developer console to confirm this?

Comment: You should check in browser as said so you know if axios did that. And on server side so you know if server did that.

Comment: Why are you not using the `tokenHeader`?

Comment: @DanielA.White that threw me off a bit too, but I don't believe `const tokenHeader` is being used at all.

Comment: No, he is not being used :/

Answer (score 1):

Try writing "Authorization" and not "authorization".
I've had this kind of problems before.

```
const projects = await axios.get('/projects', { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}});
```